# Perform join on two tables in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Consider table A and B. Entire column in table A and only one column in table B need to be taken.Previously,a named query is created with which entire column values of table A are taken. Now i need to include one column of table B too.

In DAO class,below is code

```
X x=null
 Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("AAA").setParameter("serialID",val);
 x=(X) query.getSingleResult()
```

And in DTO class, AAA is part of class X which refers to table A. The query of AAA is below:

```
select X from A X where COLUMNVAL= serialID;
```

Now, table B also has COLUMNVAL too and i need to consider value of xyz column from that table.Consider xyz is mapped in class Q.

I tried the below query for which i got classcast exception as java.lang.object cannot be cast to A

```
select X, Q.xyz from A X, B Q where X.COLUMNVAL = Q.COLUMNVAL AND X.COLUMNVAL=serialID
```

Please favour how to proceed further. A has huge number of columns so ResultList is not preferred.

Comment: you have any mappings specified?

Comment: it is all  annotations

Comment: fair enough.. can you place the most important parts

Comment: Pardon? I don't get you

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?  Are you able to run the query in another tool to check that it works?

Comment: if you have mapped those tables, you can simply fetch the B entity along with A. Or you want to have projection?

Comment: Class X doesnot contain xyz mapped but class Y has. I assume, when i perform query.getSingleResult with object X, as xyz is part of Y, it behaves this way.

Comment: I rectified the codes a little bit, You would understand mapping better.

Comment: In hql you should join tables based on query not by Cartesian.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the below query for which i got classcast exception as
>   java.lang.object cannot be cast to A
>
> select X, Q.xyz from A X, B Q where X.COLUMNVAL = Q.COLUMNVAL AND
>   X.COLUMNVAL=serialID

if you wish to use that query, you'll non get objects of class A, but instead an Array of Object where the first element is an object of class and the second element is the value Q.xyz

so you should use

```
Object[] x;
x=(Object[]) query.getSingleResult()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ResultDTO` class, which extends entity class `A` thus having all fields from class `A` and have its own required field(`xyz`) of the entity class `B`. Now you can do this to get `ResultDTO`:

```
String queryString = "select a, b.xyz from A a join B b on(a.field = b.field)"
            + " where a.serialID = :serialID";  

return (List<ResultDTO>) entityManager.createQuery(queryString)
    .setParameter("serialID", serialId);
    .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ResultDTO.class))
    .getResultList();
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to read this post [The best way to map a projection query to a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18186128)

Comment: I am sorry was not aware of that. I have added essential parts of the answer.